# How in jQuery to scrolltop to "#hash-%number%"

Tags: jquery, scrolltop

I am using the following script to scrolltop to comments sections within a blog, and if no comments section exists to scrolltop instead to "respond" which is an empty comment box:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    // Set up the onClick() event
    jQuery('.comments-link').click(scrollToComments);

    // If the page is page.php#comments scroll to the comments/response
    if (location.hash=='#comments') scrollToComments();
});

// This function handles the scrolling on page load and onclick
function scrollToComments(){
    var comments = jQuery('#comments');
    // this can be moved outside the function, or recalculate in case the page redraws
    var scrollTopPosition = (comments.length==0)? 
       jQuery('#respond').offset().top :
       comments.offset().top;
    jQuery('html, body').animate({scrollTop:scrollTopPosition}, 2000, 'swing');
    return false;
}
```

I would now also like to scroll to individual comments themselves, these are set with the ID structure "#comment-%" on the blog, so, for example "#comment-22".

Is it possible to do this in jquery somehow?

Comment: I think this can help you: http://css-plus.com/2010/11/create-a-scrolling-anchor-link-with-jquery/

Answer (score 0):

These are the things you'd need to do.

1. Match `location.hash` against a pattern instead of a text to handle the individual comments structure. You can make use of regular expression to achieve this or a simple `.startWith()` alternative.
2. Refactor `scrollToComments()` to receive a selector instead of hardcoding it.
3. If necessary, make use of the [Attribute Starts With Selector `[name^="value"]`](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/), to match the individual comments. Only needed if you want to bind them to events. Not really needed.